# GitHub pages not building "Error: undefined method `yaml_file?' for #<Jekyll::Page"

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a series of GitHub pages that are very simple. Last week I could change and rebuild the pages, but this morning when I went to make an edit to the repository I now get this error when the page is building.

```
Logging at level: debug Configuration file: 
/github/workspace / . / _config.yml 
GitHub Pages: github - pages v230 
GitHub Pages: jekyll v3 .9 .5 
Theme: jekyll - theme - primer 
Theme source: /usr/local / bundle / gems / jekyll - theme - primer - 0.6 .0 
Requiring: jekyll - github - metadata 
Requiring: jekyll - seo - tag 
Requiring: jekyll - sitemap 
Requiring: jekyll - gist 
Requiring: jekyll - feed 
Requiring: jekyll - coffeescript 
Requiring: jekyll - commonmark - ghpages 
Requiring: jekyll - github - metadata 
Requiring: jekyll - paginate 
Requiring: jekyll - relative - links 
Requiring: jekyll - optional - front - matter 
Requiring: jekyll - readme - index 
Requiring: jekyll -
    default -layout 
Requiring: jekyll - titles - from - headings 
GitHub Metadata: Initializing...
Source: /github/workspace / .
Destination: /github/workspace / . / _site 
Incremental build: disabled.Enable with--incremental 
Generating...
EntryFilter: excluded / package.json 
EntryFilter: excluded / Gemfile.lock 
EntryFilter: excluded / Gemfile 
EntryFilter: excluded / Gruntfile.js 
EntryFilter: excluded / LICENSE 
Generating: JekyllOptionalFrontMatter::Generator finished in 4.5195e-05 seconds.
Generating: JekyllReadmeIndex::Generator finished in 5.3681e-05 seconds.
Generating: Jekyll::JekyllSitemap finished in 0.001898873 seconds.
Jekyll Feed: Generating feed
for posts 
Generating: JekyllFeed::Generator finished in 0.000658672 seconds.
Generating: Jekyll::Paginate::Pagination finished in 3.427e-06 seconds.
Generating: JekyllRelativeLinks::Generator finished in 0.003758912 seconds.
Generating: JekyllDefaultLayout::Generator finished in 0.000167654 seconds.
Generating: JekyllTitlesFromHeadings::Generator finished in 1.7644e-05 seconds.
Rendering: pages / 01 - platform - description.md 
Pre - Render Hooks: pages / 01 - platform - description.md 
Rendering Liquid: pages / 01 - platform - description.md 
Rendering Markup: pages / 01 - platform - description.md 
Requiring: kramdown - parser - gfm 
Rendering Layout: pages / 01 - platform - description.md Layout source: site 
Rendering: pages / 01 - platform - description.md / 
#excerpt Pre - Render Hooks: pages / 01 - platform - description.md 
#excerpt github - pages 230 | Error: undefined method `yaml_file?' for #<Jekyll::Page @name="01-platform-description.md">
```

An example GitHub page is available here:
https://github.com/kap-field-manual/kap-field-manual.github.io

I have only changed the content in the `index.md`.